# VS Code shows multiple versions on Finder control-click (right-click) action on MacOS

Tags: visual-studio-code

On the OSX Finder right-click (control-click) menu, I see:

[image: Finder menu]

Selecting older versions actually seems to run the older version.
I have only one package, named "Visual Studio Code.app", in the usual Applications folder.
I did previously have the Insiders build installed for testing, in case that's a factor.

Is there any way to clean up / remove older versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/64126/463635).
The command
`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user` took a few seconds to run.

On restarting the Mac, the duplicates were gone.
MacOS 11.6.7.